# How to create a function to count total characters in structure array's string item?

Tags: c, arrays

I define a structure type `Monitor`, and setting `P000`, `P100`..... 
Because I will not know the size of array in the `P000` and `P100 ...`. So first I need to know the size of array. Then according the size of array to calculate the array item `Name` total characters in `P000`.

For example: 
in array `P000` the array size is 5 and total character are 27 `char`. I would like to use a function just like `Uint16 CalculateCharacter(MonitorData P[])` that input array data `P000 P100` ... Then calculate size of this array , using this size of array to calculate character and return this value? Thanks!

```
    Uint16 CalculateCharacter(MonitorData P[])
typedef struct Monitor MonitorData;
 struct Monitor
    {
        int     No;
        char    *Name;
        int     Value;
    };
MonitorData P000[] =
    {
         { 0, "DA1_T/" , 0 },
         { 1, "DA2/" , 1 },
         { 2, "DA3_S/" , 1 },
         { 3, "DA4/" , 1 },
         { 4, "DITest/" , 0 },
    };
MonitorData P100[] =
    {
         { 0, "Teffdf/" , 0 },
         { 1, "ss/" , 1 },
         { 2, "rrd3/" , 1 },
         { 3, "ffff/" , 1 },
    };
```

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you are looking for something like the following:

```
int countChars(MonitorData data[], int size) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        count += strlen(data[i].Name);

    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int size = sizeof(P000) / sizeof(P000[0]);
    printf("%d\n", countChars(P000, size));
    return 0;
}
```

This functions takes a MonitorData array and its number of elements. You can  find its number of elements by getting its total size in bytes and dividing by the size of the first element. The function then, for each element in your array, increments count by the length of each Name field. Hope this helps :)

Comment: `MonitorData data[]` is an *incomplete type* and invalid as a parameter to a function passing an array.

Comment: Also, note, notwithstanding the incomplete type, `data` will decay to a *pointer* when passed as a parameter to a function, so `sizeof (data) / (sizeof (data[0])` will be `sizeof (a pointer) / sizeof (an element)` Not what you are thinking.

Comment: Why I use `P000` to this `countChars` function, the `size=0` not array count?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I changed so that size is now passed as an argument. I had forgotten about pointer degradation. However, I still do not get your first comment. It compiles just fine on my machine without any errors or warnings.

Comment: I dont really understand the question. Could you rephrase it? @sarah

Comment: Much better. You will want to review [6.7.6.2 Array declarators p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p4) .